# Rerunning a code based on inputs

Tags: python

```
print("=======================PHONE ONE INPUT=============================")
    global name1
    name1=input("1).      What brand is your phone? ")
    condition=input("2).      What is the condition of your phone (new or used)? ")
    camera=input("3).      Does the phone have a Camera (true or false)? ")
    GPS=input("4).      Does the phone have GPS (true or false)? ")
    WiFi=input("5).      Does the phone have WiFi (true or false)? ")
    global price1
    price1=input("6).      Enter phone price($0-$1000) : ")
    if (price1>"1000" or price1<"0"):
        print("Invalid input, please re-run the simulation")
        def main():
    else:
        computeValue(condition,GPS,WiFi,camera)
        PhoneValue1=PhoneValue
```

I am trying to make the code above rerun from the top if the user inputs a value that is greater than 1000 or less than 0. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Please format your your code so we can read it.  Select the code and then click on the braces at the top of the input box.  Thanks.

Comment: `while user_input > 1000 or user_input < 0: ...` ?

Comment: if i change it to a while loop, it wont continue on if the value is between 0-1000

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `price1` to an integer – using `int()` – instead of using it as a string if you want to use `<` and `>` for a numerical comparison:

```
price1=int(input("6).      Enter phone price($0-$1000) : "))
if (price1> 1000 or price1 < 0):
    print("Invalid input, please re-run the simulation")
    main()
```

Also, as shown above, you need to use `main()` to run your main function. `def main():` defines the function called `main`.

You probably just want to repeat this input instead of running the whole function within this one, however. You'd use a `while` loop to do this, similar to below.

```
valid_price = False
while (not valid_price):
    price1 = int(input("6).      Enter phone price($0-$1000) : "))
    if (price1> 1000 or price1 < 0):
        valid_price = True
    else:
        print("Invalid input.")
```

**Python 3\Python 2 disparity**

In Python 2, `input` will evaluate the typed expression and return the evaluated value, so typing either `5` or `2 + 3` will give you the integer `5`, for instance.

In Python 3, `input` is the same as `raw_input` in Python 2, which interprets the given input as a string, hence `5` will give you `"5"` and `2 + 3` will give you `"5"`. This is why we need to use `int()` above to convert the input into an integer.